# media queries working locally but not when uploaded to website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

So I have this really weird problem. My media queries work very well when I test them locally, however, when I uploaded the files to my website, the server doesn't seem to notice the media queries, it notices one of them which is the first one but the ones for smartphones, it just skips and displays all the elements that I've hidden for all screen sizes. I'm certain they're correct because they work locally. Anyway, here's the html and css.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<header>
 <div class="container">
   <h1 id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="index/logo.png" alt="logo"/></a></h1>
 <div class="dropdown">
   <img src="index/mobilemenubutton.png" id="menubutton">
 <div class="dropdown-content">
   <ul id="nobullets">
     <li class="center"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li class="center"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
     <li class="center"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 </div>







    #container_2, #navi, #infoi, #smartphone_main_col, .dropdown, .dropdown-
    content {
   display: none;
  }

 @media screen /*THIS ONE WORKS*/
 and (max-width: 1367px) {
.slider {
  display: none;
}
.fader {
  display: block;
}
#navi, #infoi {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#infoi {
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 2s;
}

#infoi:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

#container_2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#other_f {
  position: relative;
  top: 650px;
}

#newsletter {
  z-index: 3;
}

.button_1 {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #0099ff;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 4px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: -2;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: all 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3.3px;
}

footer {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
}
}

 /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ---------- */ /*THIS ONE DOESN'T WORK*/
  @media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){
  .slider, .slides, .slide, #infoi, #navi, footer {
  display: none;
}

#background {
   background-color: #d2d8d0;
}

.container {
   width: 100%;
   margin: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding-right: 0;
}

header {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   border-bottom: #0099ff 4px solid;
}

#logo {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   right: 25px;
   bottom: 30px;
}

.dropdown {
   position: absolute;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

#menubutton {
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  left: 30px;
}

#nobullets {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.center {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 0px;
}

.center:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #35424a;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 80px;
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.link-1 {
   display: none;
}

#smartphone_main_col {
   display: block;
   padding-left: 40px;
   padding-right: 40px;
   padding-top: 80px;
}

#newsletter {
   height: 80px;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   padding-top: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
}

#newsletterhead {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
  left: 34px;
}

#newsletter input[type="email"] {
  padding: 4px;
  height: 23px;
  width: 185px;
  transition: 1s;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 35px;
  float: left;
}
.button_1 {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #0099ff;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 4px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 18px;
  padding-bottom: -12px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 7px;
  transition: all 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: -16px;
  right: 35px;
}   

}
```

Comment: One closing bracket is missing in your second media query

Comment: Naa, I left it out when copying the code by mistake, everything works fine locally.

Comment: Does the phone you're trying it with apply to those css queries? meaning his screen width is between 320PX and 480PX?
Try to remove the max-width and see if it works, If so than that's where your problem is.

Comment: Just tried that now, still getting the same. I'm stumped

Comment: It would be good to see the live code... my first guess would be to inspect the code live on the website, and check to see if the host and domain has been configured incorrectly with one of those crappy redirects that loads all of the content in through an iframe, so media queries will not work.

Answer (score 2):

So I've finally figured it out guys, I had user-scalability set to no, I just set it to yes and deleted temp files in my browser and it's working just fine.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-
  scalable=yes"> <!--THIS-->
 <meta name="description" content="Affordable and professional web design">
  <meta name="keywords" content="web design, affordable web design, 
 professional web design, portfolio">
<meta name="author" content="Stefan Vujic">
<title>Light Designs | Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try place mobile css front pc css like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){...}
@media screen and (max-width: 1320px){...}
```